# Extjs MVC run function after store loads

Tags: json, extjs, grid, extjs4

I've got a grid getting data through a json store. I want to display the total number of rows in the grid. The problem is that the store.count() function is running before the store loads so it is returning 0. How can I get my count function to run only once the store has loaded? I'm working in MVC, here is my app.js which has my counting logic in it.

Thank you for any help

```
    Ext.application({
            name: 'AM',
            appFolder: 'app',
            controllers: [
                    'Users'
            ],
            launch: function(){
                  Ext.state.Manager.setProvider(Ext.create('Ext.state.CookieProvider'));
                  Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
                            resizable: 'true',
                            forceFit: 'true',
                            layout: 'fit',
                            items:[{
                                    xtype: 'userpanel',
                            }]
                  });
                  var     port = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('viewport')[0],
                          panel = port.down('userpanel'),
                          grid = panel.down('userlist'),
                          label = panel.down('label');
                  var count = grid.store.getCount();
                  var labelText = "Number of people in list: " + count;
                  label.setText(labelText);
            }
    });
```

store code:

```
Ext.define('AM.store.Users', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'AM.model.User',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    purgePageCount: 0,
    proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url: 'json.php',
            reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'queue',
                    successProperty: 'success'
            }
    },
sortOnLoad: true,
    //autoLoad: true,
    sorters: [
            {
                    property: 'PreReq',
                    direction: 'DESC'
            },
            {
                    property: 'Major1',
                    direction: 'ASC'
            },
            {
                    property: 'UnitsCompleted',
                    direction: 'DESC'
            }
    ],
listeners:{
            onload: function(){
                    var     port = button.up('viewport'),
                            grid = port.down('userlist'),
                            panel = port.down('userpanel'),
                            label = panel.down('label'),
                            count = grid.store.getCount(),
                            labelText = "Number of people in list: " + count;
                    label.setText(labelText);
            },
            scope: this
    }
});
```

grid code:

```
Ext.define('AM.view.user.List' , {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.userlist',
    store: 'Users',
    height: 'auto',
    width: 'auto',
    //resizable: 'true',
    features:[{
            ftype: 'grouping'
    }],
autoFill: 'true',
    layout: 'fit',
    autoScroll: 'true',
    initComponent: function() {
            function renderTip(value, metaData, record, rowIdx, colIdx, store) {
                    metaData.tdAttr = 'data-qtip="' + value + '"';
                    return value;
            };
            var dateRender = Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m/d/Y');
            this.columns=[
                //code for all my columns
            ]
            ];
            this.callParent(arguments);

}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured it out, needed to add a listener for the "load" event, not "onLoad". Code below...

```
Ext.define('APP.store.Store', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    model: 'APP.model.Model',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    purgePageCount: 0,
    proxy: {
            type: 'rest',
            url: 'json.php',
            reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    root: 'users',
                    successProperty: 'success'
            }
    },
    sortOnLoad:true,
    sorters: [{
            property: 'last',
            direction: 'ASC'
    }],
    listeners: {
            load:{
                    fn:function(){
                            var label = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#countlabel')[0];
                            label.setText(this.count()+ ' Total Participants);
                    }
            }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try putting a listener on the store then listen for the onload event get the count and update the field that way. Though there are many ways to do this that is just one.

But in the example above you never load the store you just create it, which is why you see zero.

Comment: When I create the viewport, it calls the panel, which calls the grid, which calls the store. Does that count as loading the store?

I added this to my store file as a listener:
 listeners:{
                onload: function(){
                //code to update field
                },
                scope: this
        }
 but that still doesn't work

Comment: I made a button that also updates the count field which works fine, since the code runs when you press it (after the store has loaded)

Comment: the event is load not onload